# RecyclerView inside the bottomsheet is not working

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, bottom-sheet

Following are my xmls

MainView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Your content -->
    <include layout="@layout/content_main"/>

    <!-- Bottom Sheet -->
    <include layout="@layout/main_bottom_sheet"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

BottomSheet View

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation_sheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="56dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_bottom_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

RecycleView Screen

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:background="@color/white"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_height"
        android:background="@color/alabaster"
        android:elevation="@dimen/elevation_normal"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        tools:targetApi="lollipop">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/search_as_you_type_back_button"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/toolbar_height"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_height"
            android:foreground="?selectableItemBackground">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:contentDescription="@string/accessibility_back"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_arrow_back"/>

        </FrameLayout>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/search_as_you_type_edit_text"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_medium"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textColor="@color/darkest_grey"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_medium"
            tools:text="Chocolate"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/search_as_you_type_close_container"
            android:layout_width="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:foreground="?selectableItemBackground"
            android:visibility="invisible">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/search_as_you_type_close"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:contentDescription="@string/accessibility_close"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_cancel_grey_24dp"/>

        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ViewFlipper
        android:id="@+id/view_flipper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:inAnimation="@android:anim/fade_in"
        android:outAnimation="@android:anim/fade_out">


      <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
          android:id="@+id/auto_suggest_list"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
          android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"/>


    </ViewFlipper>

</LinearLayout>
```

Fragment bottom container layout will be inflated with a fragment which has recyclerview screen. The Recyclerview here is not scrolling after populating it with data. As well its not getting adjusted when the keyboard pops up. I tried setting windowssoftInputMode. Could someone help in how to solve this.

Comment: did you find solution ?

Comment: We have this working - are you still having this issue?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60696081/4921704 see this answer that might help.

Answer (score 15):

This is the working code for `RecyclerView` inside BottomSheet

XML:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerViewMore"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />
          
        </RelativeLayout>

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</layout>
```

In Java in `onCreateView`

```
B.recyclerViewMore.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        v.onTouchEvent(event);
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: work like a charm, it's should be accepted an answer

Answer (score 14):

lincy's solution didn't work for me. The events never got through to the `OnTouchListener`.

My solution is to wrap the `RecyclerView` with a custom layout that hooks into `dispatchTouchEvent`:

```
<info.mschmitt.view.TouchEventInterceptorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />

</info.mschmitt.view.TouchEventInterceptorLayout>
```

The code for `TouchEventInterceptorLayout` (constructors removed):

```
public class TouchEventInterceptorLayout extends FrameLayout {
    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        boolean handled = super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
        requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        return handled;
    }
}
```

That will recursively disable touch event handling in all parents for the current touch interaction, leaving only the `RecyclerView` as a target for processing.

Why all of this is necessary I don't know. Maybe it's a bug in Google's BottomSheet implementation.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much!

Comment: My app will always crash with this error "Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10 in com.imincode.earthlings:layout/generic_item_list: Error inflating class com.imincode.earthlings.helpers.TouchEventInterceptorLayout
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.imincode.earthlings.helpers.TouchEventInterceptorLayout.<init> [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]"

Comment: nvm I got it fixed. Need to use the constructor `public TouchEventInterceptorLayout(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }`

Comment: class TouchEventInterceptorLayout @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null
) : FrameLayout(context, attrs)

Answer (score 1):

You need to block touch events to parent(BottomSheet) when user is scrolling the list. Try this code.

```
recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(@NonNull RecyclerView rv, @NonNull MotionEvent e) {
            rv.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTouchEvent(@NonNull RecyclerView rv, @NonNull MotionEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
rv.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
    v.onTouchEvent(event);
    return true;
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This one is a optimization of @Matt solution as it was not working on my case.

```
class TouchEventInterceptorLayout(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) :
FrameLayout(context, attrs) {
override fun dispatchTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent): Boolean {
    val handled = super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev)
    requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)
    return handled
}}
```

And wrap the recylerview like this

```
<com.demo.view.TouchEventInterceptorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</com.demo.view.TouchEventInterceptorLayout>
```