# RecyclerView in BottomSheet not working as expected

Tags: android

I have a problem with RecyclerView directly inside of layout with bottomsheetbehaviour. The problem is that when bottom sheet is expanded and content is scrolled down, when I go to scroll back up it causes Bottom Sheet to start collapsing, instead of RecyclerView first being scrolled back to top.

Here's a [video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Yr0A0H731XEGwhXjMhqC7vKIaMjH79RZ/view?usp=sharing) to demonstrate the problem. As you can see the problem appears when I scroll down on expanded bottom sheet. It immediately start to collapse instead of "waiting" for RecyclerView to scroll to top first.

Here is my layout code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scheduleRoot"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".schedule.ScheduleFragment">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/scheduleSheet"
        app:behavior_peekHeight="300dp"
        android:elevation="16dp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_bottom_sheet"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/scheduleRecyclerView"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution for this one? I am facing the same issue

Comment: @makiskontis check my answer, I had the same problem, but I fixed it.

Answer (score 6):

Add

```
android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
```

in the root layout of BottomSheetDialogFragment.

Comment: this is working but with this way BottomSheet not dismissing when slide down

Comment: Besides the note of @MehmetGür said, this also makes around 3 items of the `RecyclerView` is hidden below the screen

Answer (score 5):

I just encountered same problem, but I fixed it by adding this to onCreate:

```
androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(recyclerview, false);
```

Comment: This is not a good idea, as it will mean that your recycler view is not a recycler view, it will instantly render all cells (assuming you have it pared wrap content as otherwise your cells will just be cutoff).

Answer (score 3):

The recyclerview is not scrolling because in case of BottomSheet, all its touch events are getting consumed by the Bottomsheet(Parent). You can block the touch events to parent(BottomSheet) when user is scrolling the list.

```
recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(@NonNull RecyclerView rv, @NonNull MotionEvent e) {
            rv.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTouchEvent(@NonNull RecyclerView rv, @NonNull MotionEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue: Maybe the solution to my problem will give you some ideas. My bottom sheet was expanded to full height with recycler view in it; the bottom sheet was collapsing on user-drag, even though the first item in recycler view wasn't visible yet.

So, what I did:

1. You can enable/disable bottom sheet dragging by "isDraggable" = true/false
2. Add OnScrollListener for recycler view.
3. Override onScrolled and check layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition() in it
4. If first item is visible - update bottom sheet behavior.isDraggable = true, i also added small delay before setting behavior.isDraggable = true, because bottom sheet was collapsing too fast, but you might not need it

Maybe it's not optimal but it was fitting my needs and maybe will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your recyclerview item has overighted the scrolling state, so this error generates. The layout you provided does not have enough data to determine the cause. You change the item is a unique view to check

Answer (score 0):

I played with this for a long time and tried way too many solutions. For me, this worked best:

```
        val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
        binding.recyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager
        binding.recyclerView.setOnScrollChangeListener { _, _, _, _, _ ->
            if (bottomSheetBehavior.state == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED) {
                bottomSheetBehavior.isDraggable = layoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() == 0
            } else {
                bottomSheetBehavior.isDraggable = true
            }
        }
```

The key to the solution is is controlling users ability drag the bottom sheet while the recyclerview is partially scrolled. The method only allows scrolling again once the top most cell is fully visible.

Its not ideal as the user may want to grab the very top of the bottom sheet (assuming its not part of the recycler view) and dismiss the bottom sheet regardless of its scroll position. Im just accepting.

Whatever you do, **do not try these**, as they just disable any recycling functionality and all cells are loaded at instantiation having a really bad impact on performance:

```
wrap_content
```

or:

```
binding.recyclerView.isNestedScrollingEnabled = false
```

Comment: Nice trick, but as you've mentioned, it has it's own caveats... It works great only if your BottomSheet contains single RecyclerView, if you have other Views, it might be confusing to user, why that BottomSheet could not be dismissed. Did you try other approaches? F.e., inheriting from default BottomSheetBehavior and changing motion event intercepting, so it wouldn't intercept RecyclerView events?

Comment: @d.u.a.l No I didn't but there could be some good solutions in there! For me, the less ideal approach was just about acceptable.

Answer (score -1):

Enable the scroll state of BottomSheet to allow scroll if recyclerview 0th item is visible.

> activity_main.xml

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data />

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#A8A7A7"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:behavior_hideable="true"
        app:behavior_peekHeight="80dp"
        app:layout_behavior="com.asadmukhtar.recyclerviewinsidebottomsheet.LockableBottomSheetBehavior"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Drag Me"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_items"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</layout>
```

> LockableBottomSheet file that used for handling allow dragging option or not.

```
class LockableBottomSheetBehavior<V : View?> : BottomSheetBehavior<V> {
    private var mAllowUserDragging = true

    constructor()

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(
        context,
        attrs
    )

    fun setAllowUserDragging(allowUserDragging: Boolean) {
        mAllowUserDragging = allowUserDragging
    }

    override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(
        parent: CoordinatorLayout,
        child: V,
        event: MotionEvent
    ): Boolean {
        return if (!mAllowUserDragging) {
            false
        } else super.onInterceptTouchEvent(parent, child, event)
    }
}
```

> MainActivity.java

```
var bottomSheetBehavior: LockableBottomSheetBehavior<*>? = null
lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding =
        DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)

    setUpBottomSheetBehaviour()

    binding.rvItems.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    binding.rvItems.adapter = RecyclerViewAdapter(this)

    binding.rvItems.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

        override fun onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView: RecyclerView, newState: Int) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState)

            val firstPosition = (binding.rvItems.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager)
                .findFirstVisibleItemPosition()

            updateBottomSheetLockState(firstPosition == 0)
        }
    })

}

fun updateBottomSheetLockState(allow: Boolean) {
    bottomSheetBehavior?.setAllowUserDragging(allow)
}


fun updateBottomSheetState(state: Int) {
    if (bottomSheetBehavior != null) {
        bottomSheetBehavior?.state = state
    }
}

private fun setUpBottomSheetBehaviour() {
    val bottomSheetBehavior: BottomSheetBehavior<LinearLayout> =
        BottomSheetBehavior.from(binding.parent)
    this.bottomSheetBehavior = bottomSheetBehavior as LockableBottomSheetBehavior<*>
    updateBottomSheetState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED)
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Your implementation might need more coding and with the provided code we might not able to give you good feedback.

Try this documentation 
https://material.io/develop/android/components/bottom-sheet-behavior/

Plus I found this another implementation.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WeaylHAwIIk

Comment: So there is no way to do this through XML alone? I find that strange since it seems like a list in bottom sheet is failry common bahaviour. Also, the second link looks like what I want, I'll check out the implementation, thanks!

Comment: Implementation that you have found works perfectly but I don't see any custom code to take care of desired behavior.