# How to show bottom dialog

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, dialog

**I want to implement show dialog when user clicked on a button `showBottomDialogBtn`**

**And I also want to implement recyclerView with single item selection**

You can check this image in this

[image: image link]

Comment: Use _BottomSheetDialog_

Comment: can you show me how to it I am new to android @Piyush

Comment: Check https://medium.com/@anitas3791/android-bottomsheetdialog-3871a6e9d538 or https://medium.com/glucosio-project/moving-from-dialogs-to-bottomsheetdialogs-on-android-15fb8d140295

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [bottomsheetdialogs-on-android](https://medium.com/glucosio-project/moving-from-dialogs-to-bottomsheetdialogs-on-android-15fb8d140295), https://droidbyme.medium.com/android-bottom-sheet-7e9cfcec6427 .

Small example:

[BottomSheetDialogTest.kt](https://gist.github.com/kozimovbotirali/f1e9d84f80a02a5c58e2e5d24d07a40f)

```html
// imports...

class BottomSheetDialogTest : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {
    private var _binding: DialogTestBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!
    var _data: ArrayList<SomeDataClass> =  arrayListOf()

    private val adapter by lazy { SomeAdapter() }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
        _binding = DialogTestBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        loadViews()
        loadData()
    }

    private fun loadData() {
        adapterAll.submitList(_data)
    }

    private fun loadViews() {
        binding.apply {
            listAll.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
            listAll.adapter = adapterAll
            adapter.setOnItemClickListener {
              //your click actions                
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        binding.listAll.adapter = null
        _binding = null
    }
}
```

[dialog_test.xml](https://gist.github.com/kozimovbotirali/a9e99736dc4550fb05d1b6182fa8aedd)

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bottom_sheet_dialog_bg"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/list_all"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Then use it like that in your fragment or activity:

```html
//some code
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
      //init your ui
        btnShowDialog.setOnClickListener {
                val dialog = HomeSelectSortTypeDialog()
                //...
                dialog.show(childFragmentManager, "HomeSelectSortTypeDialog 1")
            }
    }
```

And sorry for my English! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get this by creating a `CoordinatorLayout`, a layout with the `BottomSheetBehavior` and a `RecyclerView`.

Follow [this guide](https://material.io/components/sheets-bottom/android#usage) to get a working example of the bottom sheet, and for the recycler view inside, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57393736/16279195) seems good (java).